# Manual Proxy Configuration not working on Android 2.3

Tags: android, proxy, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S Plus Phone running on Android 2.3.4

I manually set the proxy server and the port in the phone, in Settings-> Wireless & Network-> Wi-Fi Settings-> MENU Button-> Advanced panel.

My phone is still not able to communicate using the proxy. I tried the browser, and that is not able make use of the proxy settings.

```
public static InputStream inputStreamForUrl(URL url) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // doesn't work on android 2.3.4
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        System.out.println(urlConnection.usingProxy());
        urlConnection.connect();
        return urlConnection.getInputStream();
}
```

However, If I manually hardcode the proxy in the code, it works

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.server.url", 8080));// this needs to be hard coded to make it work in 2.3
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);// this needs to be hard coded to make it work in 2.3
```

I tried to dynamically find out the system proxy and then use it in code,

```
private static void getProxySettings()
    {
        final boolean IS_ICS_OR_LATER = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14;

        String proxyAddress = "";
        int proxyPort = 0;

        if( IS_ICS_OR_LATER )
        {
            proxyAddress = System.getProperty( "http.proxyHost" );

            String portStr = System.getProperty( "http.proxyPort" );
            proxyPort = Integer.parseInt( ( portStr != null ? portStr : "-1" ) );
        }
        else
        {
            proxyAddress = android.net.Proxy.getHost( ctx );
            proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getPort( ctx );
        }



        System.out.println(proxyAddress);
        System.out.println(proxyPort);
    }
```

but the proxy address and port is null always.

Can someone help please

**PS.** I absolutely no problem on Android 4.1/4.2/4.3 devices